# beep remote tmux when job is done

Tags: ssh, tmux, mutt

im a linux fan.

A few days ago i found tmux very useful.

Now im using it all day. 
I run tmux on a remote shell and working there. On my local pc only one terminal working.
And i found interesting thing: 
my mutt program is beeping when new mail arrives. And tmux is transferring this beep to my local PC, is there a way to run similar beep by any shell command ? 
I want to use it for some command finishing sign.

Comment: remotely related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25211/is-there-a-way-to-make-tail-f-beep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a little script called beep.sh that I use for things like that:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $'\a' > `/usr/bin/tty`
```